Continuation of convergence in $L^1$
If $X_n\to X$ in $L^1$ and $Y_n\to Y$ in $L^1$, and $(X_n)$ are bounded, then we have $\|X_nY_n-XY\|_1\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.
Indeed, assume $|X_n|\leq M$, then
$$
\|X_nY_n-XY\|_1\leq\|X_n(Y_n-Y)\|_1+\|(X_n-X)Y\|_1\leq M\|Y_n-Y\|_1+\|(X_n-X)Y\|_1.
$$
The first term on the right side is easy, but how to deal with the second term $\|(X_n-X)Y\|$? I want to show $\|(X_n-X)Y\|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

This is Exercise III.4.12 on Erhan's probability and stochastics book

Use Dominated Convergence Theorem. Since $X_n\to X$ in $L^1$, you get that $X_n\to X$ in probability. Thus, $X_nY\to XY$ in probability. Now $|X_nY|\leq M|Y|$ which is integrable, so by DCT, $X_nY\to XY$ in $L^1$.
